# Visual Studio 2017 RC3 has wrong version of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis

Tags: code-analysis, visual-studio-2017

When compiling any of the modelling projects in VS2017 RC3, the compilation fails because it tries to use Microsoft.CodeAnalysis 2.0.0.0. However only 1.3.2 is installed with RC3.

There is a NuGet prerelease 2.0.0.0 of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, but installing this does not help.

Is there a way to install the code analysis 2.0.0.0 in VS to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed in the latest update to VS 2017 RC